# Selector function for a custom rxjs store

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this selector function which helps me select a slice of my custom store, but only a slice or the entire store.

```
  select<K>(mapFn: (state: T) => K): Observable<K> {
    return this.internalState$.asObservable().pipe(
      map((state: T) => mapFn(state)),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
  }
```

And I use it like this

```
this.title$ = this.store.select((s) => s.title)
```

Works ok but I came in a situation where I need two pieces of my state. I solved it like this
`this.store.select((s) => s).pipe(map((m) => ({ date: m.date, zone: m.zone })))` or selecting the entire store and in the next pipe using the properties I need or using combineLatest with the selected states.

Is there a way to create a selector which will pick the properties of the store? I've used `Pick<T>` before, but I don't know how to apply it here.

Comment: `.select((s) => s)` doesn't do anything. You can simply do: `this.store.select(s => ({ date: m.date, zone: m.zone }))`

Comment: So simple yet I didn`t see it. Could you please add it as an answer so I can marked it solved?

Comment: Sure, done. Glad it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.select((s) => s)` doesn't do anything on its own.

Instead you should do:

```
this.store.select(s => ({ date: s.date, zone: s.zone })).pipe(

)
```